# How to put background Image in paragraph that has break-inside css

Tags: html, css, svelte

I put the break-inside css in one of the paragraph inside the page and clicked print button.

As I expected the paragraph went to the next page when it was breaked by the page, but at the next page the background image was not applied. It was just a white background page.

Is there a way to solve this?

Or is there a way to know the next page most top div? thing?

```
<div class="page">
 <div class="paragraphBreak w-[95%] mx-auto">
    <div>Example one</div>
 </div>
 # This paragraph will go to next page because the first paragraph will be very long
 <div class="paragraphBreak w-[95%] mx-auto">
    <div>Example two</div>
 </div>
 <div class="paragraphBreak w-[95%] mx-auto">
    <div>Example three</div>
 </div>
</div>

<style>
    .page {
        background-image: url('/src/lib/images/pdf/background.png');
        background-size: contain;
        background-repeat: repeat-y;
        width: 210mm;
        margin: 20px auto;
    }


    @media print {
        .page {
            width: 210mm;
            height: 296.8mm;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            page-break-before: always !important;
            print-color-adjust: exact;
            border: 0;
        }

        .paragraphBreak {
            break-inside: avoid;
        }
    }
</style>
```